# Black smudge under navigation controller when transitioning

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

When I'm tabbing between pages attached to a navigation controller, sometimes there is a black mark under the navigation bar..

[image]

any ideas how to remove this?

they're just blank pages.

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: page)
            self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

i have tried setting background to white in navigation controller class like some threads recommend which didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

The "smudge" happens when you transition between a view controller whose `edgesForExtendedLayout` include `.top` and one that does not. To avoid it, make sure all your view controllers have the same `edgesForExtendedLayout` and the same `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` settings.

Answer (score 0):

for me, It happens when I use ToolBar from libraries. fix by using ToolBar from the navigation controller itself by toggle "Shows Toolbar" in Navigation Controller's Attribute Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my app as well, except I had a black smudge under the Navigation Bar *and* a Toolbar. I eventually discovered that the problem was because of the `isTranslucent` property of the `UIToolbar` I had in multiple scenes.

[image: translucent property in storyboard editor]

Once I set this property to false, the black smudge under *both* the Navigation Bar and the Toolbar went away (why disabling translucency on the Toolbar fixes the Navigation Bar as well, I don't know). I had tried disabling `isTranslucent` on the `UINavigationBar`, but that only fixed the smudge on top. Luckily, in my case, nothing will ever be under the Toolbar, so disabling translucency is not a problem. If translucency under the Toolbar is required, this solution may not work for you.