# Swift black background appears behind navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue, uistoryboardsegue

!NOTE: I've seen some other questions reporting about a black bar appearing but that question is not a duplicate (correct me if I am wrong) for me there is something like a black view appearing when I my push segue is executed. Non of the solutions for the problem with the black bar worked for me (difference: There is a black view appearing for me).
I used the standard "show" segue in the storyboard. The following is the code inside `viewDidLoad` of my first `UIViewController` (this vc performs the segue to my second vc):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController!.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}

mapView.delegate = self

locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

This is the code inside `viewDidLoad` of my second vc (the segue leads to this vc):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController!.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

They both use the same `navigationController`. For my first vc I want the navBar `preferresLargeTitles = false` and for my second I want the navBar to `preferresLargeTitles = true` that's what I am doing inside the `viewDidLoad` methods. The 5 lines about `MapKit` and `CoreLocation` shouldn't cause this effect but I don't know why this black view appears so I left these lines of code. How can I remove that black view which is appearing behind my navBar when the segue is performed? (when the segue is completed the black color disappears) (The black color in top right corner is what's bothering me)[image]

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842359/black-smudge-under-navigation-controller-when-transitioning

Comment: That's apparently the same problem but the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: you push scene using segue ? can you show your segue function please

Comment: I don't have any code for my segue, I sued the standard push segue in the interface builder (storyboard).

Answer (score 7):

Changing `.backgroundColor` for `navigationController.view` solved this issue for me.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `.backgroundColor` for `navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance` (`UINavigatioBarAppearance`) solved this issue for me.

example:

```swift
let scrollEdgeAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

scrollEdgeAppearance.backgroundColor = // your color or .clear

navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollEdgeAppearance
```