# Navigating to a view controller with a transparent navigation bar from a non-transparent navigation bar on iOS 15

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios15, uinavigationbarappearance

On iOS 15, when navigating to a view controller that has a transparent navigation bar, the animation to the transparent bar isn't working as expected.

However, if you navigate back to the view controller with a transparent navigation bar, the animation works as expected.

This is how I've set up my view controllers:

**rootVC**

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

**firstVC**

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

**secondVC**

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

Notice in the following example how smooth the transition is from **secondVC** -> **firstVC** but not from **rootVC** -> **firstVC**:

[image: video demonstration]

Example project: https://github.com/karlingen/NavigationTest

Any ideas why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Isn't it kind of unsupported to change the navigation bar transparency as part of the navigation? It's supposed to just sit there consistently.

Comment: Also could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842359/black-smudge-under-navigation-controller-when-transitioning ?

Comment: @matt why would it be unsupported? The docs doesn't say anything about that, unless I've missed something?
Also, this works fine on iOS < 15

Comment: Well that's why I said "kind of" :)

Comment: Transition between transparent and opaque navigation bars always been choppy on iOS. I would recommend to use third-party lib for that. I had good experience with this one: https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMNavigationBarTransition

Comment: @ManWithBear it has worked fine up until iOS 15

Comment: @matt Fixed! See solution below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the following reply from Apple:

> You should get better behavior using per-item customization, that is setting these properties on their view controller’s UINavigationItem instead of on the UINavigationBar itself. This also frees you from the strict timing necessary for the viewWillAppear: approach to work – as long as your customizations are applied before the view controller is pushed, you should get a good transition. viewDidLoad is generally a good place to do these customizations when using the per-item customization support.

So we should be using `UINavigationItem` instead.
Using the following code fixed it for me:

```
# firstVC.swift    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    
    self.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```